# How to manage lifecycle of instances with TestInstanceFactory?

Tags: junit5, junit5-extension-model

I'm using JUnit 5.3.0-RC1, trying to implement an extension for the new `TestInstanceFactory` interface. (I want to get the objects from Weld for CDI injection etc.)

If I implement `TestInstanceFactory` I can create my own instances. If I also implement `AfterEachCallback` I can clean them up (shut down Weld) after each test. So far, so good.

However: for this I have to assume `TestInstance.LifeCycle.PER_METHOD`. If the test class uses `TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS` I would have to detect this and wait until `AfterAllCallback` before destroying Weld. But `ExtensionContext.getTestInstanceLifecycle` is declared as `Optional`, so I may not be able to tell which Lifecycle is active.

Is there a way of having JUnit simply tell me when to destroy the instance? It would be nice to have an extension like `TestInstanceDestructor`, which would be called whenever JUnit has finished using the test instance.

Secondly, `AfterEachCallback` is never called for `@Disabled` tests, which means I can't clean up the instances which were created through my `TestInstanceFactory`. Starting Weld is kind of expensive, so ideally I'd skip doing that work for disabled tests anyway. Is there some way I can tell which instances are being created for disabled tests?

Answer (score 1):

> But `ExtensionContext.getTestInstanceLifecycle` is declared as `Optional`, so I may not be able to tell which `Lifecycle` is active.

As discussed in the [JUnit 5 Issue Tracker](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1575#issuecomment-417854460), you can reliably detect which `Lifecycle` mode is active.

> Is there a way of having JUnit simply tell me when to destroy the instance?

You previous proposal implementing `AfterEachCallback` or `AfterAllCallback` based on the current `Lifecycle` should suffice.

But keep in mind that you can always store a `CloseableResource` in the `ExtensionContext.Store` if you want to clean up something after the *current* context is closed. You can also opt to store such an object in the *parent* `Store` if your extension is currently executing at the method level.

> Is there some way I can tell which instances are being created for disabled tests?

No, I don't think that is possible. A `TestInstanceFactory` never knows anything about the method about to be executed, since a `TestInstanceFactory` is invoked at the class level.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Especially for the tip about the Store.

Regarding disabled tests, if [this feature](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1568) were to be implemented, would it cover the case where I want to skip expensive test instance construction for tests which are disabled? I could check for the `@Disabled` annotation on the Method object, but in view of other ExecutionConditions I suspect I wouldn't have everything I need.  Does that sound right?

Comment: The only way to know if a test method is _disabled_ is to allow the framework to actually evaluate all registered `ExecutionCondition` extensions. So I don't see how one could _know_ the outcome in advance, but perhaps I'm overlooking something.